# jquery before/after animate like show/hide

Tags: jquery

Can you control the animation speed of the before / after functions in jQuery like
you can with show/hide?
eg. is there an equivalent to `$('.someClass').show('slow')`
but for the after and before functions.

Comment: what do you mean? before and after are jQuery selectors. Are you talking about some sort of plugin?

Comment: @Loktar It's simpler than that, I believe grouping both kinds of functions [like this](http://stackoverflow.com/a/32522792/1326147) is what Sausage wanted.

Answer (score 4):

`before` and `after` are not animations at all.  They insert elements into the dom before or after another element.  If you wanted to animate this element being inserted, you could have it initially hidden.  Then use `before` or `after` to insert it, then `show` as you described.

Comment: I know what they do, however I use before after dynamically based on user interaction and it would like to animate that.

Comment: I **don't** think you know what they do.  All they do is insert something into a big list.  It's like asking to animate "1 + 1".  It just doesn't make sense.  Kingjiv gave a surprisingly good answer (for the question) for how you'd reveal "2".

Comment: Hah, I was about to get offended until I saw the "(for the question)" part.

Answer (score 1):

Your question and James' answer allowed me to "animate" the (consequences of using) [before](http://api.jquery.com/before/)/[after](http://api.jquery.com/after/)/[prepend](http://api.jquery.com/prepend/)/[append](http://api.jquery.com/append/) functions in this way:

```js
$('button').click(function() {
  var clickedBtn = $(this);
  el2Animate = $('.someClass');
  el2Animate.hide('fast');
  setTimeout(function() {
    if (clickedBtn.attr('id') === "before")
      el2Animate.siblings('.someOtherClass').before(el2Animate);
    else
      el2Animate.siblings('.someOtherClass').after(el2Animate);
    el2Animate.show('fast');
  }, 300); //transition delay
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<ul>
  <li>a</li>
  <li class="someOtherClass">b</li>
  <li>c</li>
  <li class="someClass">d</li>
  <li>e</li>
</ul>
<button id="before">Go2B4!</button>
<button id="after">Go2After!</button>
```

Remembering that in [show](http://api.jquery.com/show/)/[hide](http://api.jquery.com/hide/):

> `'fast'` and `'slow'` can be supplied to indicate durations of 200 and 600 milliseconds

A [setTimeout](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/WindowTimers/setTimeout) of 300 milliseconds works well with `fast`: I am pleased with the results.